# How to implement a constant declarating macro to behave differently in preamble and pspicture?

Tags: pstricks, best-practices, programming, fp

The example below is extremely trivial just to illustrate the problem in the simplest way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% constants declarator
\def\LoadConstants{}% to load PostScript constants defined in the preamble
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
                        \ignorespaces}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=25pt\relax


\const{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
\begin{pspicture}(\Side,\Side)
    \LoadConstants
    \psframe(!Side dup)\pause
    \multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
        \const{temp}{cos(\i*pi/180)}
        \LoadConstants
        \rput{\i}(!Side 2 div dup 2 copy temp mul add 3 1 roll \i\space sin mul add){\temp}\pause
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Background:

1. I have to use `beamer` document class to take advantage of overlays to create a step-by-step animation.
2. I also have to use `preview` to get a tight output.
3. Using `beamer` and `standalone` document classes is not possible to substitute for the 2 requirements above.
4. I have to define constants in TeX world and PostScript world at the same time. The constants are most likely defined by algebraic expressions involving trigonometry and logarithm.
5. If possible constants should be defined in the preamble.
6. But `preview` discards PostScript constants defined in the preamble. That is why `\LoadConstants` must be invoked inside `pspicture` environment to deal with this issue.
7. `\LoadConstants` by design should be invoked just once.
8. However, sometimes I need additional constants to be defined inside `pspicture`. Invoking `\LoadConstants` for the additional constants will make redundancies because `\LoadConstants` made of concatenated strings of `\pstVerb`.
9. Mostly I use `standalone` document class so `\LoadConstants` can also be invoked in the preamble.

### Objectives:

1. I want to have a single `\const` to be smart enough to detect whether it is invoked in the preamble or inside `pspicture`.
2. When `\const` is invoked in the preamble, it must prepare `\LoadConstants` by concatenating the corresponding `\pstVerb`.
3. But when `\const` is invoked inside `pspicture`, it just invoke `\pstVerb` at that location. **NOTE:** Be careful because `\pstVerb` has a trailing white space.
4. As a bonus, if you can, please inject `\LoadConstants` to `pspicture` environment such that I don't need to invoke `\LoadConstants` at first.
5. Any idea to improve the code is welcome!

Comment: You can check if you're past `\begin{document}` by checking whether `\document` is `\ifx`-equal to `\@notprerr` (but this is not any more true if you use the `standalone` *package*).

Comment: @egreg: I don't use `standalone` package but `standalone` document class.

Comment: Oh my ghost! When `\i=300` the output is not `0.500000` but `0.499999`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% constants declarator
\def\LoadConstants{}% to load PostScript constants defined in the preamble
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\SpecialCoor
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=25pt\relax
\makeatletter
\def\pst@@picture@i[#1]#2(#3,#4){%
  \renewcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{trunc(##3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname##2\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\temporary:##1)}%
    \pstVerb{/##2 \csname##2\endcsname\space def}\ignorespaces}%
  \@ifnextchar(%   ignore anything between [] and ()
  {\pst@@@picture[#1](#3,#4)\LoadConstants}%
  {\pst@@@picture[#1](0,0)(#3,#4)\LoadConstants}}
\makeatother

\const{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
\begin{pspicture}(\Side,\Side)
    \psframe(!Side dup)\pause
    \multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
        \const{temp}{cos(\i*pi/180)}
        \rput{\i}(!Side 2 div dup 2 copy temp mul add 3 1 roll \i\space sin mul add){\temp}\pause
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you but you just did the bonus question that is injecting the `\LoadConstants` inside `pspicture`.

Comment: and added the other part ...

Comment: There is a bug as mentioned [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112096/19356)